# Tensorflowのモジュールが読み込めない

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

Python初心者です。有識者に教えて頂きたいことがあります。
anacondaの仮想環境にコマンドプロンプトで

```
conda install tensorflow
```

を入力して、tensorflowをインストールしました。

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

が Jupiter Notebook 上でエラーなく通っているので、installには成功していると考えています。
しかし、

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
```

を実行しようとすると、

```
No module named 'tensorflow.examples.tutorials'
```

というエラーが出てしまいます。
このモジュールはtensorflowと一緒にダウンロードされるものかと思ってたんですが、違うんですかね…
エラーなく実行する方法を教えてほしいです。

目的は下記URLのサイトでやっていることと同じことをしようとしています。

[tensorflowで手書き数字を認識させてみた - Qiita](https://qiita.com/hacoten/items/6ae9219cd6a094863386)

実行環境は以下の通りです。
python 3.7
jupiter notebook 6.0.3
anaconda3
windows10 64bit

Comment: 参照している記事に載っている「ソースコード」の部分全体を1つのファイルとして実行する必要があると思うのですが、エラーになるのは "from tensorflow.examples ..." の部分1行だけを実行しようとして…ということでしょうか？

Comment: import tensorflow as tfとfrom tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data を同時に実行したら出ました。全体で実行しようとしても、同じエラーがでます。

Answer (score 1):

`tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist.input_data` は [deprecated になりました](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/026b504c1de272ac379cdc33e7afd70d375a76fb/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py#L15-L18)。また　`tensorflow.examples.tutorials` は pip パッケージに[含まれなくなった](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7933#issuecomment-283562188)のでパッケージをインストールするだけでは使えなくなりました。

このため参照されている Qiita の記事のコードを動かすには、自分で examples のコードをローカルに配置する必要があります: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples

また初心者の方であれば https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials にある公式チュートリアルを行う方がラクですし古い方法を使わなくて済みます。たとえば MNIST のデータをロードするだけであれば `tf.keras.datasets.mnist` を使うことになるでしょう。以下は例です。

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```